# select multiple nodes in single xpath

Tags: php, html, xpath

how can i select all the `<tr>`s from this html element, and then

1. select /small/a from the first td
2. select /small/i from the second td
3. select /small from the third td
4. select /small from the fourth td
5. select /form from the sixth td

i want to use the information got from here in php as array or object

thanks in advance

```html
<tbody><tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="title">Applications</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="header-left"><small>Path</small></td>
    <td class="header-left"><small>Version</small></td>
    <td class="header-center"><small>Display Name</small></td>
    <td class="header-center"><small>Running</small></td>
    <td class="header-left"><small>Sessions</small></td>
    <td class="header-left"><small>Commands</small></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small><a href="/">/</a></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small><i>None specified</i></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small>Welcome to Tomcat</small></td>
    <td class="row-center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small>true</small></td>
    <td class="row-center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small><a href="/manager/html/sessions?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=7DF475B8EF3807C4BCA8651FEBA676EA">0</a></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        &nbsp;<small>Start</small>&nbsp;
        <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/stop?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=7DF475B8EF3807C4BCA8651FEBA676EA">  <small><input value="Stop" type="submit"></small>  </form>
        <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/reload?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=7DF475B8EF3807C4BCA8651FEBA676EA">  <small><input value="Reload" type="submit"></small>  </form>
        <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/undeploy?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=7DF475B8EF3807C4BCA8651FEBA676EA">  <small><input value="Undeploy" type="submit"></small>  </form>
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <form method="POST" action="/manager/html/expire?path=/&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=7DF475B8EF3807C4BCA8651FEBA676EA">
            <small>
                &nbsp;<input value="Expire sessions" type="submit">&nbsp;with idle ≥&nbsp;<input name="idle" size="5" value="30" type="text">&nbsp;minutes&nbsp;
            </small>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small><a href="/item1/">/item1</a></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small><i>None specified</i></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small>&nbsp;</small></td>
    <td class="row-center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small>false</small></td>
    <td class="row-center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small><a href="/manager/html/sessions">0</a></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3">
        <form class="inline" method="POST" action="item1Start">
            <small>
                <input value="Start" type="submit">
            </small>
        </form>
        &nbsp;<small>Stop</small>&nbsp;
        &nbsp;<small>Reload</small>&nbsp;
        <form class="inline" method="POST" action="item1Undeploy">
            <small>
                <input value="Undeploy" type="submit">
            </small>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small><a href="/item2/">/item2</a></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small><i>None specified</i></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small>&nbsp;</small></td>
    <td class="row-center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small>false</small></td>
    <td class="row-center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><small><a href="/manager/html/sessions">0</a></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/sessions?path=/manager">  <small><input value="Start" type="submit"></small>  </form>
        &nbsp;<small>Stop</small>&nbsp;
        &nbsp;<small>Reload</small>&nbsp;
        <form class="inline" method="POST" action="/manager/html/sessions?path=/manager">
            <small>
                <input value="Undeploy" type="submit">
            </small>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small><a href="/manager/">/manager</a></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small><i>None specified</i></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small>Tomcat Manager Application</small></td>
    <td class="row-center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small>true</small></td>
    <td class="row-center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#C3F3C3"><small><a href="/manager/html/sessions?path=/manager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=7DF475B8EF3807C4BCA8651FEBA676EA">33</a></small></td>
    <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3">
        <small>
            &nbsp;Start&nbsp;
            &nbsp;Stop&nbsp;
            &nbsp;Reload&nbsp;
            &nbsp;Undeploy&nbsp;
        </small>
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="row-left" bgcolor="#C3F3C3">
        <form method="POST" action="/manager/html/expire?path=/manager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=7DF475B8EF3807C4BCA8651FEBA676EA">
            <small>
                &nbsp;<input value="Expire sessions" type="submit">&nbsp;with idle ≥&nbsp;<input name="idle" size="5" value="30" type="text">&nbsp;minutes&nbsp;
            </small>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: `/td[1]/small/a | /td[2]/small/i` and so on

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-UnionExpr

Comment: if dont use the starting slash on td it will go for all TDs and create an array of contents so "td/small" will give you the contents of all <small> elements that are inside <td> element in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i select all the s from this html element, and then

I don't know what `s` is, but I assume you mean elements by the 1-5 requirements? Since you use PHP, I will assume XPath 1.0.

### XPath 1.0

You didn't say it, but I actually think you want to select all `tr` (except the first two) and from each `tr` the x<sup>th</sup> `<td>` and from each column a certain value.

So let's start with `tbody/tr[position() > 2]` and then:

> select /small/a from the first td

add `/td[1]/small/a`

> ```
> select /small/i from the second td
> ```

add `/td[2]/small/i`

> select /small from the third td

add `/td[3]/small`

> select /small from the fourth td

add `/td[4]/small`

> select /form from the sixth td

add `/td[6]/form`.

Get the pattern? In essence, XPath is quite straightforward. Now all we need to do is combine them. As was already said in the comments, just use the union operator `|`. This will give us:

```
tbody/tr[position() > 2]/td[1]/small/a
| tbody/tr[position() > 2]/td[2]/small/i
| tbody/tr[position() > 2]/td[3]/small
| tbody/tr[position() > 2]/td[4]/small
| tbody/tr[position() > 2]/td[6]/form
```

That's it!

Now, if you were to use XSLT (assuming you want to do something with this set), you'd be able to do this much simpler by applying templates on `tr` and then simply create templates for each of your requirements. No complex, nested if-statements needed.

### XPath 2.0

For completeness, here's the XPath 2.0 version (slightly more readable):

```
for $tr in tbody/tr[position() > 2]
return 
    $tr/td[1]/small/a,
    $tr/td[2]/small/i,
    $tr/(td[3] | td[4])/small,
    $tr/td[6]/form
```

Or, if the structure of your HTML does not contain errors, you can write it even simpler (also XPath 2.0):

```
tbody/tr[position() > 2]/td[not(position() = 5)]
/(small/(i | a) | small[not(i|a)] | form)
```

Unfortunately, PHP does not yet support XPath 2.0, though you can use a third party XPath 2.0 processor and call its interface from PHP.